# Transplanckian energy magnetic monopoles in string theory/M-theory

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, dark-matter, magnetic-monopoles

I was thinking about transplanckian energy $E>10^{19}GeV$ magnetic monopoles in string theory and M-theory. Are they possible in Nature like the Dirac, 't Hooft Polyakov, Julia-Zee monopoles/dyons? What are the issues (if any) from theory/experiment?

The answer should contain ideally also answer to some of the following items:

1. How could transplanckian energy Kaluza-Klein (or others) magnetic monopoles be generated in the Universe?
2. Could they be part of/all the dark matter?
3. Are they problematic if looked at the inflation paradigm?
4. Does the inflation killing magnetic monopoles apply as well to magnetic monopoles?
5. What experimentally distinct signals would they produce?
6. Where could we find them?
7. Are they non-relativistic or could they be relativistic in some special conditions?

Comment: What do you mean by "transplanckian energy"? I think a mosquito has transplanckian energy, in the sense that its rest mass is greater than the Planck mass... The only significant issue I can think of, is that if it's dense and heavy enough, a monopole may be a black hole.

Comment: @MitchellPorter I mean what I wrote: transplanckian energy is energy greater than Planck energy. Magnetic monopoles with the size of a subatomic particle could be black objects (indeed, I know about black branes but I was afraid to ask for them). I mean elementary particles with such an energy, but the size is open in my question. I will not ask here if the monopoles have size of elementary particles or bigger. Of if they are invisible, that is another interesting point if magnetic monopoles are...dark.

Comment: But you get my point about the mosquito, right? The fact that a mosquito has a mass greater than the Planck mass has no significance for entomology, because it's an extended object. Monopoles are extended objects too, so why would transplanckian mass make a difference?

Comment: I guess they could be created in transplanckian scattering processes

Comment: @MitchellPorter Transplanckian scattering processes are renormalizable? I have never seen a calculation of String+String -> Monopole, or its amplitude, for example...